# Forwarding Outlook mails to another Email automatically as they arrive

Tags: outlook, gmail

I have 2 email accounts one Gmail and another Outlook.I want to receive the mails that are coming into outlook to gmail automatically as they arrive.How can i do that?
Is there any security restriction to outlook that can be a blocker for this?

**NOTE**- I used the rule settings to set a rule,but i'm not getting the mails into another mailbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login into your [Outlook](http://outlook.live.com) email.

1. Click on the **settings icon**, which is located in right top corner of your dashboard.
2. Under the drop down menu select **Options**
3. On `left sidebar`, select **Mail**
4. Under **Mail** -> **Accounts**, select **Forwarding**
5. Enter the email you want to forward your mails to. Then click **save**

Done.

All the incoming emails will be forwarded to the email you entered above.

Comment: i've done this @nulldev. But i'm not getting the mails in another mailbox

Comment: hey @Gouthamgauti, I have edited the post try that one.

Comment: For me there's no "Forwarding" under Mail -> Accounts: there's only "Block or allow", "Connected accounts", "POP and IMAP". I tried to add a "connected account" but it said it couldn't connect through a secure connection.